What triggered an automatic "Spam" flag for this question?
This question

My key has been either jammed/ or got broken inside the lock, I tried multiple tricks to pull out the key, but none of the methods worked. Would appreciate any advice that can help me resolve my problem.

Was flagged as spam:


Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

What in the world looks spammy about this??

If it's any comfort, the question was not reported to metasmoke as spam.

Possibly the user's other post, Can someone recommend a reliable, local locksmith in Adelaide?, which was downvoted and closed with the "product/service recommendation" reason.
I suspect that close reason feeds into the heuristic that SE uses to highlight posts as possible spam in the review queues, but a) I don't have strong evidence to support that, and b) SE keeps some information about the inner workings of their algorithms secret to prevent gaming.
Note: the post wasn't flagged as spam, just highlighted in the review queue so that reviewers could decide if it actually is spam and then flag it for moderators to handle.

Ah, that makes sense.
